# Application for Facebook Chat

Tags: chat

Is there a native Linux application which allows chatting on Facebook Chat? A feature which I particularly require is being able to chat in conversations which include multiple people.

Comment: Pidgin supports Facebook chat, but I don't know whether it supports multi-people conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Chat is based on XMPP. Any XMPP client will work for normal chatting.  Group chat is possible with XMPP (specified in XEP-0045) so you will need to look for a client that supports XEP-0045.  Pidgin should support this (as there are closed bug reports for fixed history issues relating to Multi-User Chat [MUC]).  Empathy and most popular XMPP clients should support this feature though.